# Select2 not removing id from token list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 to assign content to other users (multiple tags). It all works great except I can not find out how to remove assignees once added.

Once I have added a user to the list of assignees in my modal, after I click the cross with class `select2-search-choice-close`, the corresponding list item with class `select2-search-choice` is deleted from the input field, but the id is not removed from assignee tokens (and is thus passed to the controller when I submit the form).

What am I missing?

NOTE: I am not 100% sure whether this is related, but I noticed that the assignee_ids passed when I submit the form sometimes contain the same id several times (e.g: assignee_ids => "12,1,4,4").

This is how I initialize the input:

```
    $('#assignable_item_assignment_assignee_ids').select2({
      minimumInputLength: 2
      tags: true
      tokenSeparators:[',', ' ']
      createSearchChoice: (term, data) ->
        {id: term, new_choice: true}
      multiple: true
      ajax:
        url: url
        dataType: 'json'
        quietMillis: 150
        data: (term, page) ->
          query: term
        results: (data, page) ->
          return {results: data}
      formatResult: userFormatResult
      formatSelection: userFormatSelection
      formatInputTooShort: (term, minLength) ->
        "Search existing users or assign by email"
      dropdownCssClass: 'select2'
    })
```

And this is the form I am using:

```
  <%= form_for AssignableItemAssignment.new, url: assignable_items_assignments_path, html: { class: "form-horizontal", id: "new-assignment" }  do |f| -%>
    <fieldset>
      <div class="control-group">
        <%= f.label :to %>
        <div class="with-spinner">              
          <%= f.text_field :assignee_ids, placeholder: "Search users by name or email", class: 'select2'  %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
        <%= f.label :add_a_message %>
        <%= f.text_area :message, rows: 3, placeholder: "Add a message for your recipients (optional)" %>
      </div>

      <%= f.button "Submit", disable_with: 'Submiting' %>
    </fieldset>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem, which is fixed after installing latest release (3.3.2)